# How to apply each function in a list of functions to a value in one line in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Filling out a study guide without an answer key. I need to apply each function in the list of functions (fs) to a value (v) using map in one line

```
applyEach :: [a->b] -> a -> [b]
applyEach fs v = map (\v -> fs v) fs
```

This is far as I can get. I understand that I can't apply fs to a value because fs is the list of functions, but I don't know how to use each function in the list

Comment: you mean, `[a->b]->a->[b]`? (not one `b`, but a list of them?)

Comment: You want `applyEach fs v = map (\f -> f v) fs` which is `map ($ v) fs` as others have said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying a list of functions in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400825/applying-a-list-of-functions-in-haskell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `$` (`f $ x = f x`) for that:

```
Prelude> let fs = [(+1), (+2)]
Prelude> map (\f -> f 2) fs
[3,4]
Prelude> map ($ 2) fs
[3,4]
```

This works because `($ x)` is a [section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) equivalent to `\f -> f $ x` which is equivalent to `\f -> f x` (the function in your map)

Or, you can import `Control.Applicative` and use `<*>` and the list `Applicative` instance:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> let fs = [(+1), (+2)]
Prelude Control.Applicative> map (\f -> f 2) fs
[3,4]
Prelude Control.Applicative> fs <*> [2]
[3,4]
```

Comment: It's literally a fill-in-the-blank question: applyEach :: [a->b] -> a -> [b] applyEach fs v = map (__________)                                Edit: Nevermind, I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 3):

`($ v)` is a function which, given a function `f`, computes `f v`. So, just map that over `fs`:

```
map ($ v) fs
```