# Applying a list of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function that applies a list of functions to an item.

```
applyAll :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
applyAll [] _ = []
applyAll (f:fs) x = (f x) : (applyAll fs x)
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 22):

This function actually already exists as a special case of a monadic function:

```
applyAll :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
applyAll = sequence
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that `[f b] -> f [b]` unifies with `[a -> b] -> (a -> [b])` when you take `f` to be `(a ->)`. (Nevermind that it isn't valid syntax, it gets the point across best.)

Comment: @Carl, I have never understood why that is not valid syntax.

Comment: Lee's less brain-twisty solution is likely to be more efficient in some contexts, but this one gets a point for being a library function already.

Comment: @dfeuer: I think I saw, somewhere, that one reason might be because the usual section rules don't apply; for instance, `(-> b)` isn't valid in Haskell.  I agree that I still wish the irregular section syntax were available, though!  But at least there's some explanation.

Answer (score 12):

You could use:

```
 applyAll l v = fmap ($ v) l
```

`fmap` lifts a function over the input list (actually any Functor). `$` has type `(a -> b) -> a -> b` so it applies a function to a given value. `($ v)` is a [section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) which applies the given function to `v`.

Comment: When would this not be better that the explicit-recursion alternative? It's more elegant, more concise, more general, probably more optimisation-friendly, can be defined anywhere ad-hoc inline...

Answer (score 6):

Lee's solution is what I'd recommend, but this reads perhaps even nicer:

```
import Control.Applicative

applyAll' fs v = fs <*> pure v
```

or

```
applyAll'' fs v = fs <*> [v]
```

This sort of makes stuff more complicated than necessary, though: we really only need the `Functor` instance of lists, whereas `applyAll'` injects and immediately extracts from the `Applicative` instance.

Comment: This particular equivalence really helped me think about something a few months ago.